# MySql Error- ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, asp.net, wampserver

I am getting the following error while connecting to the MySql database in the wamp server.I have added the assemblies also.  How can i fix the problem?
Thanks a ton.
Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parameter '@First__Name' must be defined. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter '@First__Name' must be defined.

Source Error: 



Line 26:         cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Country", DropDownCountry.Text));
Line 27:         cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@About_User", txtUserDescription.Text));
Line 28:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 29:         con.Close();
Line 30:
```

My C# Code Behind file - Registration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=FreedomKitchen;Uid=root;Password=;");
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into User_Details(User_ID,First__Name, Last_Name, Age, Gender, Country, About_User)values(@User_ID,@First__Name, @Last_Name, @Age, @Gender, @Country, @About_User)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@User_ID",1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@First_Name", txtFirstName.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@FLast_Name", txtLastName.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Age", txtAge.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Gender", DropDownGender.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Country", DropDownCountry.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@About_User", txtUserDescription.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: `First__Name` has two underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more `_` Underscore in for parameter `@First_Name`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@First__Name", txtFirstName.Text));
```